# making Toast when receiving SMS not working

Tags: java, android, android-studio, broadcastreceiver

I'm new at android programming.

I've read a lot about doing any code when receiving an SMS but all of them is not working with me

please help!

what I want to do is making a Toast when receiving an SMS

here is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.salkhuzayyim.toastwhenreceivesms">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name=".SmsListener"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and here is SmsListner.java

```
package com.salkhuzayyim.toastwhenreceivesms;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SmsListener extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public SmsListener() {
    }

    private SharedPreferences preferences;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")){
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();           //---get the SMS message passed in---
            SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
            String msg_from;
            if (bundle != null){
                //---retrieve the SMS message received---
                try{
                    Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                    msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                    for(int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
                        msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
                        msg_from = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                        String msgBody = msgs[i].getMessageBody();


                        Toast.makeText(context, "SMS Received", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                    }
                }catch(Exception e){
                    // Log.d("Exception caught",e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and I'm using android studio, simulator is (Nexus_5X_API_25)

is there any thing I should share with you guys to make things easier ?

thanks in advance

Comment: You said API 25. `RECEIVE_SMS` is a `dangerous` permission. Have you requested to get the permission from the user? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#RECEIVE_SMS

Comment: thanks dear @th3pat3l for your reply, as I said am new at android, but isn't this line will get the permission from the user <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" /> , anyway this application will be used by me only, it's related to other project, it will not be available in the google play store

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@sulaiman

Based on your comment: No, the line below will not give you the permission you need to read SMS.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
```

You still need that line though. So do not remove it.

The reason for this is what Android calls "Runtime Permissions". Since API 23 (6.0 and above), you are required to ask for permission explicitly for all permissions with `dangerous` levels.

Please read more and understand how that works [here](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html).

As to solve this question, you need to ask for permission when you first open the app. Take a look at the [`Request Permission`](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html#perm-request) section.

Comment: thanks a lot, I just knew about the new way of permissions, that was helpful :-)